# Proper way to optimize the bandwidth while transferring the Image

Tags: image, bandwidth, data-transfer

I have a case scenario in my project where at some places I want to display a thumbnail image to reduce and optimize the bandwidth of data transfer and at some places, I need to display the original image.

In a Facebook website, they display thumbnail Image on the album cover and upon clicking that thumbnail they display the original image. so I want the same result as Facebook.

**So Which is the better way to optimize the bandwidth**

1. Store only original image on the server and retrieve that image on the client side, create thumbnail and display it.
2. Store original Image and Thumbnail Image both on the server, and retrieve original or Thumbnail Image As per Needed.

Comment: Facebook uses a thumbnail, which has a smaller filesize and therefore is faster transferred than the big original file. Loading the full file and then resizing it in the browser (option 1) is not an optimization at all. I really don't know what you want to achieve with that option